# Kona Mahuna 2013 headset change question.

Tags: headset

I have a Kona Mahuna 2013 and I got a tapered fork as well as a new wheel and now I'm looking for advice on changing my headset to accept tapered forks.

I've been looking and I believe that [this](http://www.jensonusa.com/Headsets-and-Spacers/Cane-Creek-40-ZsEc-49mm-Headset-Tapered) headset should fit correctly in my bike. According to the specs, it has an FSA No.10 ZS44 semi-integrated at the moment, stock. I just want to make sure before I would get my headset and it installed correctly in the shop with all the reaming/facing/etc. required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best place to find what headset you need is the [Crane Creek headset finder](http://www.canecreek.com/headset-fit-finder).

Unfortunately in your particular case I thought the Mahuna has a straight 1 1/8 head tube and if so (correct me if I'm wrong) and therefore won't be able to take the tapered fork (easily, people have tried different things). Tapered steerers fit in tapered and 1.5 straight (with a reducing top headset) head tubes.